# How to use Jquery for formfields

Tags: jquery

this may be a dumb question for a lot of you, but I'm new to this coding           thing.

Anayway, I'm trying to figure out how to use jquery to select the same day in

two different form fields. For example, if I select Monday on formfield

selectOne, I want to be able to have that same day, Monday, selected on

formfield selectTwo. How can I acomplish this? I'm lost.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It's easier for us to help you if you show us the code you've tried instead of telling us about it.

Comment: Please provide your code.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<select id="selectOne">
  <option value="">(Select One)</option>
  <option value="foo">foo</option>
  <option value="bar">bar</option>
</select>
<select id="selectTwo">
  <option value="">(Select One)</option>
  <option value="foo">foo</option>
  <option value="bar">bar</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#selectOne").change(function () {
  $("#selectTwo").val($(this).val());
})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emo7z3a8/)